# how To Create This Type Audio Record and Animated in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-widget

[image]

how To Create this Type of animated Record  Audio
Please Help...

Comment: https://youtu.be/wnARLByOtKA. It’s not exactly what you want, however it uses the same logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **audio_waveforms**

this plugin to generate waveforms while recording audio in any file formats supported by given encoders or from audio files.

you can use gestures to scroll through the waveforms or seek to any position while playing audio and also style waveforms.

https://pub.dev/packages/audio_waveforms